# How to use ffmpeg to add a text to avi video?

Tags: ffmpeg, drawtext

I am trying to put a simple text on the bottom of video using ffmpeg on Ubuntu 12.04 . I tried this which is suggested in several places:

```
ffmpeg -i input.avi -vf drawtext="fontfile=/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-dejavu/DejaVuSerif.ttf:text='Text to write':fontsize=20:fontcolor=black:x=100:y=100" output.avi
```

But I get this error each time:

```
ffmpeg version 0.8.3-4:0.8.3-0ubuntu0.12.04.1, Copyright (c) 2000-2012 the Libav developers
  built on Jun 12 2012 16:37:58 with gcc 4.6.3
*** THIS PROGRAM IS DEPRECATED ***
This program is only provided for compatibility and will be removed in a future release. Please use avconv instead.
Input #0, avi, from 'input.avi':
  Duration: 04:09:09.66, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 480 kb/s
    Stream #0.0: Video: mpeg4 (Advanced Simple Profile), yuv420p, 320x240 [PAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], 45 tbr, 45 tbn, 45 tbc
    Stream #0.1: Audio: mp3, 48000 Hz, stereo, s16, 64 kb/s
[buffer @ 0x860d5a0] w:320 h:240 pixfmt:yuv420p
Incompatible sample format 's16' for codec 'ac3', auto-selecting format 'flt'
[ac3 @ 0x8607a00] invalid bit rate
Output #0, avi, to 'output.avi':
    Stream #0.0: Video: mpeg4, yuv420p, 320x240 [PAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 90k tbn, 45 tbc
    Stream #0.1: Audio: ac3, 48000 Hz, stereo, flt, 200 kb/s
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0.0 -> #0.0
  Stream #0.1 -> #0.1
Error while opening encoder for output stream #0.1 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height
```

Appreciate your help.

Comment: @Banthar It solved the problem. Thanks. However the text appears on the middle any idea on how to put it at the bottom?  Thanks

Comment: `this is worked for me in windows by replacing font address. just need copy font beside video file and use that. and need x and y in our video width and height

Answer (score 6):

The documentation shows that you can use other parameters with `x` or `y` such as input video height and width and text width and height. To place the text on the bottom one method is `y=main_h-text_h`. If you want a little padding on the bottom you can use `y=main_h-(text_h*2)` To center it horizontally use `x=(main_w/2-text_w/2)`.

Comment: Can you please tell me that "main_w" and "main_h" how to set dynamic that is set by user ?

Comment: @axita.savani See https://stackoverflow.com/a/54909273/1109017 https://stackoverflow.com/a/11059494/1109017

Comment: Yup... Thank You @llogan