# How can I automatically embed commit information into a subtitles file that I'm tracking?

Tags: git, ffmpeg

I use `git` to track `*.ass` subtitle files. 
Here is example of `*.ass` file:

```
[Script Info]
; Script generated by Aegisub 3.1.2
; http://www.aegisub.org/
Title: Default Aegisub file
ScriptType: v4.00+

[V4+ Styles]
Format: Name, Fontname, Fontsize, PrimaryColour, SecondaryColour, OutlineColour,    BackColour, Bold, Italic, Underline, StrikeOut, ScaleX, ScaleY, Spacing, Angle, BorderStyle, Outline, Shadow, Alignment, MarginL, MarginR, MarginV, Encoding
Style: Default,Arial,20,&H00FFFFFF,&H000000FF,&H00000000,&H00000000,0,0,0,0,100,100,0,0,1,2,2,2,10,10,10,1
Style: titr,DejaVu     

Sans,20,&H007DDBFA,&H000000FF,&H00000000,&HFF000000,0,0,0,0,100,100,0,0,1,2,2,1,10,10,10,1

[Events]
Format: Layer, Start, End, Style, Name, MarginL, MarginR, MarginV, Effect, Text
Dialogue: 0,0:00:00.46,0:00:11.22,Default,,0,0,0,,Если это можно было бы
Dialogue: 0,0:00:03.44,0:00:08.96,titr,,0,0,0,,{\pos(20,240)\fad(600,600)}бывший министр
```

After commit I burn subtitles into video:

`ffmpeg -i video.avi -vf "ass=subtitle.ass" out.avi`

My goal is to show commit date for 10 second at the start of movie. This should be done automatically.

1) It can be easily done with by modifying `subtitle.ass` itself, but I can't do it after commit and there are other reasons.

2) It can be done by `ffmpeg` from command line: [How to use ffmpeg to add a text to avi video?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11468448/how-to-use-ffmpeg-to-add-a-text-to-avi-video)

Problem is that in this case text will be shown for the whole lenght of movie.

3) I can copy *.ass file to temporary directory, insert date, render and delete *.ass file.

Is there a simpler way?

Comment: The third approach (add the commit date to a temporary file, use it, then delete it) seems to be the easiest. Could you edit your question to add the head (first 20 lines, say) of one of your `*.ass` files, so we know what they're made of?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your third approach seems easy enough. Here is a possible implementation of it.

[image]

The tree structure I used is

```sh
$ tree
.
├── burn_sub_w_commit_date
├── sub_repo
│   └── sub.ass
└── test_video.avi
```

where

- `burn_sub_w_commit_date` is a shell (bash) script,
- `sub.ass` is the original subtitles file you posted in your question,
- `sub_repo` is a Git repository that keeps track of your work on `sub.ass` (and that contains at least one commit),
- `test_video.avi` is just some video I found on Youtube.

Here are the contents of `burn_sub_w_commit_date`:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
# burn last commit date with subtitles in video

# exit on any errors
set -e

# extract the head of test.ass and copy it to a temporary file
sed '/Dialogue:/,$d' sub.ass > temp_head.ass

# extract the tail of test.ass and copy it to a second temporary file
sed -n '/Dialogue:/,$p' sub.ass > temp_tail.ass

# write the commit date to a third temporary file
printf "Dialogue: 0,0:00:00.00,0:00:10.00,Default,,0,0,0,,`git log -1 --format="%cD" | sed 's/ [+\-][0-9]\{4\}//'`\n" > temp_mid.ass

# concatenate all three temporary files into a fourth one
cat temp_head.ass temp_mid.ass temp_tail.ass > temp.ass

# clean up (delete the first three temporary files)
rm temp_head.ass temp_tail.ass temp_mid.ass

# burn subtitles into the video
ffmpeg -i "../test_video.avi" -vf "ass='temp.ass'" "../test_video_out.avi"

# clean up (delete the last temporary file)
rm temp.ass
```

Now, if you `cd` to `test_video/sub_repo` and run

```sh
sh ../burn_sub_w_commit_date
```

the subtitles will be burn into the video and the date of the last commit on the current branch, in my case

```
Sun, 24 Aug 2014 00:01:23
```

will be shown for 10 seconds at the very beginning.

Of course, you may want to improve automation; making the script executable and let it accepts the relevant paths as arguments seems like the next obvious step... but the basic idea is there.

Comment: Oh, thank you for detailed answer! Nothing left for me to do! ))