# Scripting FFmpeg to move text in y co-ordinate by some delta at specific time-codes

Tags: ffmpeg, drawtext

I'm using the basic drawtext command like this

```
ffmpeg -i output.mp4 -vf \
'drawtext=textfile='textfile.txt':x=0:y=0 \
:fontsize=30:fontcolor=white:borderw=3 \
:bordercolor=black:box=0' output.mp4"
```

which puts stationary text at location (x, y) = (0,0)

What I want to do is move this text by 10 points in y plane at certain time codes.

```
at 00:00:10, y would be 0
at 00:00:11, y would be 10
at 00:00:43, y would be 20
...
...
at 00:10:44, y would be 30
```

so the 'y' co-ordinate has a fix increment of 10 at 'keytimes'

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basic method is to use an expression of the form,

```
y='lte(t,10.99)*0+between(t,11,42.99)*10+between(t,43,643.99)*20+gte(t,644)*30'
```

Each sub-expression is of the form of `time-qualification * position` and only one time-qualification evaluates to 1 for any segment of the timeline.

Comment: I'm a bit unfamiliar with this syntax so let me know if I'm wrong. So the `between(t, a, b)` will I'm guessing check if `a == t` and if true, move `y` by `10`. I'm not sure what `42.99` means in the second expression. Also not sure why `99` and what `lte`/`gte` would be.

Comment: Ah `42.99` means retain position till `42.99`!

Comment: That's awesome! Thanks!