# ffmpeg - how to stop scrolling text in the middle of screen

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I can create scrolling text on ffmpeg :

```
ffmpeg -y -f lavfi -i color=c=black:s=800x450:d=125 -vf "[in]drawtext=fontfile=Futura.ttc:fontsize=40:fontcolor=#444444:x=w-(200*t):y=((h)/2):text='Ha Ha Ha'[out]" -c:v libx264  -t 5 scrolling.mp4
```

How do I make the text stop when it is in the middle of the screen or ((w-w_text)/2)?

I tried using lte() function. as suggested by [ffmpeg - how does moving overlay / text command work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11058479/ffmpeg-how-does-moving-overlay-text-command-work)

```
ffmpeg -y -f lavfi -i color=c=black:s=800x450:d=125 -vf "[in]drawtext=fontfile=Futura.ttc:fontsize=40:fontcolor=#444444:x=lte(w-(200*t), (w-w_text)/2):y=((h)/2):text='HA HA HA'[out]" -c:v libx264  -t 5 scrolling.mp4
```

It comes up with error :

```
Either text, a valid file or a timecode must be provided
Error initializing filter 'drawtext' with args 'fontfile=Futura.ttc:fontsize=40:fontcolor=#444444:x=lte(w-(200*t)'
```